# Navigation bar visited selector not changing color

Tags: css

I am having problems with my navigation bar. I want it to show a different color after the link has been visited. I read an answer from code academy, Stack O/F and other sites saying that "The pseudo-class_selector must follow the following order for it to work.
:link
:visited
:hover" (codeacademy-Submitted by Samrudhi Sharma). I tried this, but nothing happened. I've really gotten myself confused now. Thanks for your help.
My code:

```
#nav {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 5.5px solid red;
        border-bottom: 5.5px solid red;  
        line-height: 1.8em; 
        display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
 }

#nav ul {
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style: none;
 }  

#nav ul li {
    color: orange;
    font-size:1.5em;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;

}

#nav ul li a {
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:visited a{
    background:yellow;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover a{
    background:#C60;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `a:visited` on the `<a>`.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/4yqR5/1/) (Click "Run" in the jsfiddle header if the yellow does not render.)

CSS

```
#nav li a:visited  {
    background:yellow;
    color:#F00;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: That worked!! Several weeks ago I ran across instructions detailing how to create a horizontal nav bar and the instructions had an explanation for each element. I thought I saved it.

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there :) What you have now is a good basic foundation which you can improve and learn from.

Comment: Also, if the user visits each page once the whole nav bar will be visited... I'm not sure if `a:visited` is useful with navigation.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the pseudo-classes on your anchor, not on the list element. So `a:visited` instead of `li:visited`, because you visit the anchor's link, not the list element's ;)

Comment: Your explanation will help me a lot for future nav bars. Thanks